# How to change default port(15672) of RabbitMQ Management plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am running a RabbitMQ Management console on a machine where port above 10000 range are blocked using firewall. Can I change the port so that I can use any one of 9000 range ports ?

Please help!

Comment: Check this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#configuration (the first link from google search.)

Comment: @zaq178miami - I tried to configure /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config as "[{rabbit, [{tcp_listeners, [8181]}, {collect_statistics_interval, 10000}]}, {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 8282},{ip, "127.0.0.1"}, {ssl,      true},{ssl_opts, [{cacertfile, "/path/to/cacert.pem"},{certfile,   "/path/to/cert.pem"},{keyfile,    "/path/to/key.pem"}]}]}]}]." and restarted rabbitmq server.

Comment: @Gas - Thanks , I tried as per page. Could see tcp_listener changed from 5672 to 8181, but management console is still blocked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RabbitMQ has a config file `rabbitmq.config.example` or just `rabbitmq.config` under `/etc/rabbitmq` directory on linux servers.

Locate the `rabbitmq_management` tuple and change the port value (default is `12345`, change it to whatever you want).

Be sure to uncomment or add the following content into `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` file as shown below.

```
{rabbitmq_management,[{listener, [{port, 12345}]}]}
```

Then restart the RabbitMQ server instance once

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart`

Comment: Could you please edit the answer with path of rabbitmq.config ?

Comment: In my case it was `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`

Answer (score 5):

Normally, RabbitMQ doesn't comes with config file, so you need to create it:

```
sudo nano /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

And you can add this content

```
%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% RabbitMQ Sample Configuration File.
%%
%% Related doc guide: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html. See
%% http://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html for documentation ToC.
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[
 {rabbit,
[

]},

{kernel,
[
]},


{rabbitmq_management,
[
{listener, [{port,     3009}
            ]}
]},

{rabbitmq_shovel,
[{shovels,
[
]}

]},

{rabbitmq_stomp,
[
]},


{rabbitmq_mqtt,
[
]},

{rabbitmq_amqp1_0,
[
]},

{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap,
[
]},
{lager, [
]}
].
```

As you can see, I changed my rabbitmq_management port to 3009 according to the firewall of my server.

After that, you need to modify the /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf by adding this 
 line:

```
export RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq"
```

The .config will be automatically added.

By the end, just restart the service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation explains it well: https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html
What makes me respond here is all above responses although correct, they use the legacy "syntax", the new and recommended way of configuring RabbitMQ moves away from the Erlang legacy style, story short:

```
management.tcp.port = 15672
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#rpm -qa  | grep rabbit
rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.el7.noarch
#rpm -ql  rabbitmq-server-3.6.10-1.el7.noarch

search file like /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server

cat  /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server | grep RABBITMQ_ENV

RABBITMQ_ENV=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-env



open file # vi /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-env 

*change according to you port 

#DEFAULT_NODE_PORT=5672
DEFAULT_NODE_PORT=2055
```

After change first kill rabbitmq process and then restart.